# ParallelTable gets slower when rerun in a module

Tags: parallelization, scoping

**Question:** Why does the performance of `ParallelTable` within a `Module` drop so horribly when the module is RERUN several times? Actually, I am not interested in parallel computing here, but on what is being blown up and causes the parallel computations to take longer when you rerun the module. I also used `Block` and the slow-downs disappear, but I dont understand why. Is it because of the generation of unique local variables in `Module` and its scoping? Do these variables get stored somewhere, need to be checked every run for creating unique new ones and cause slower computation somehow when combined with automatic parallel programs? If yes, then it is kind of weird, since modules without automatic programs seem to be ok, see comparison below.

**Context:** Just for fun, I wanted to test `ParallelTable` (I have 4 kernels) within a module and check its time performance. Consider the following modules

```
LaunchKernels[]
Compute[data_, 1] := Module[
   {n1, n2},
   {n1, n2} = Dimensions[data];
   Table[Total[data[[i11]]*data[[i12]], Infinity], 
     {i11, n1}, {i12, n1}, {d, 1, n2}]
   ];
Compute[data_, 2] := Module[
   {n1, n2},
   {n1, n2} = Dimensions[data];
   ParallelTable[
    Total[data[[i11]]*data[[i12]], Infinity], 
      {i11, n1}, {i12, n1}, {d, 1, n2}]
   ];
```

Its not really important, what is computed, but the time performance discussed later after rerunning. As an example, just create data as a 2 by 10 matrix and check identical computations of the normal module `Compute[data,1]` and the parallelized `Compute[data,2]`

```
n1 = 2;
n2 = 10^1;
data = RandomInteger[{0, 10}, {n1, n2}];
Compute[data, 1] == Compute[data, 2]

(*True*)
```

**First run:** Now, just do some calculation time check for increasing the number of rows and columns and plot the results (y axis is computation time, x axis are number of columns, blue: one row, orange: two rows)

```
n1max = 2;
n2max = 10^1;
t = ConstantArray[, {n1max, n2max}];
Do[
 tloc = {};
 dataloc = RandomInteger[{0, 10}, {n1, n2}];
 Do[
  AppendTo[tloc, AbsoluteTiming[Compute[dataloc, i];][[1]]]
  , {i, 2}
  ];
 t[[n1, n2]] = tloc;
 , {n1, n1max}
 , {n2, n2max}
 ]
plot = 
  Table[
    ListPlot[t[[;; , ;; , i]], 
      PlotRange -> {0, Max[t]}, 
      PlotLabel -> "Compute " <> ToString[i], 
      Joined -> True, 
      PlotLegends -> Automatic], 
    {i, 2}] // TableForm
```

[image: first run]

**Rerun:** now, rerun the test just several times (here just 10 times) and look at the last evaluated time performance of the module with `ParallelTable`, it is now an order of magnitude slower while the the module with the standard `Table` shows naturally no changes!

```
nrerun = 10;
Do[
  t = ConstantArray[, {n1max, n2max}];
  Do[
    tloc = {};
    dataloc = RandomInteger[{0, 10}, {n1, n2}];
    Do[
      AppendTo[tloc, AbsoluteTiming[Compute[dataloc, i];][[1]]]
      , {i, 2}
      ];
    t[[n1, n2]] = tloc;
    , {n1, n1max}
    , {n2, n2max}
    ]
  , {rerun, nrerun}
  ]
plot = 
  Table[
    ListPlot[t[[;; , ;; , i]], 
      PlotRange -> {0, Max[t]}, 
      PlotLabel -> "Compute " <> ToString[i], 
      Joined -> True, 
      PlotLegends -> Automatic], 
    {i, 2}] // TableForm
```

[image: rerun]

If you keep rerunning or just doing more computations with the modules, the time performance keeps getting worse.

**Question:** Why does the performance of `ParallelTable` within a `Module` drop so horribly when the module is RERUN several times? Actually, I am not interested in parallel computing here, but on what is being blown up and causes the parallel computations to take longer when you rerun the module. I also used `Block` and the slow-downs disappear, but I dont understand why. Is it because of the generation of unique local variables in `Module` and its scoping? Do these variables get stored somewhere, need to be checked every run for creating unique new ones and cause slower computation somehow when combined with automatic parallel programs? If yes, then it is kind of weird, since modules without automatic programs seem to be ok, as in the example above.